# Autofac Func<T> with InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

When evaluating `Func<T>` where T is registered with `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope`, inside a singleton class, shouldn't it provide the same instance? that is, shouldn't `Func<T>` be "scope-aware"?

Maybe an example would be better.

I have two class:

```
    class MyScoped
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
    }

    class MySingleton
    {
        readonly Func<MyScoped> scoped;

        public MySingleton(Func<MyScoped> scoped)
        {
            this.scoped = scoped;
        }

        public void Do()
        {
            var scopedObj = scoped();

            Console.WriteLine(scopedObj.Num);
        }
    }
```

Which are registered like this:

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MyScoped>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("MyScope", "root");
        builder.RegisterType<MySingleton>().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();
```

And I am running the following piece of code:

```
        var singleton = container.Resolve<MySingleton>();

        singleton.Do();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("MyScope"))
        {
            var scoped = scope.Resolve<MyScoped>();

            scoped.Num = 1;

            singleton.Do();
        }
```

**I would expect that the first call to `Do()` would print 0, and the second would print 1.**

I had to changed `MySingleton` to `InstancePerDependency` so it would work, which is a bad solution for me, because `MySingleton` can be expensive to create.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is the normal behavior. You register `MyScoped` with `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` of "MyScope" then "root". *Autofac* will first look for the first matching lifetimescope which is "MyScope" and then look if there is any instance of `MyScoped` inside this scope. If not it will create a new one. If you remove "MyScope" in your `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope` declaration it will work as expected. Could you explain us what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems services registered as single instance are resolved in the context of root scope. It means that your `Func<MyScoped>` injected to `MySingleton` would always resolve `MyScoped` from the root. The following code:

```
var singleton = container.Resolve<MySingleton>();
var s = container.Resolve<MyScoped>();

s.Num = 1;

singleton.Do();

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("MyScope"))
{
    var scoped = scope.Resolve<MyScoped>();

    scoped.Num = 10;

    singleton.Do();
}
```

would print 1 twice, because `var scopedObj = scoped();` in `Do()` method would resolve `MyScoped` from root container, not from the scope.

You could achieve what you want by passing required dependency manually into `Do()` method:

```
class MySingleton
{
    public void Do(MyScoped myScoped)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myScoped.Num);
    }
}

// ...

var singleton = container.Resolve<MySingleton>();
var s = container.Resolve<MyScoped>();

s.Num = 1;

singleton.Do(s);

using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("MyScope"))
{
    var scoped = scope.Resolve<MyScoped>();

    scoped.Num = 10;

    singleton.Do(scoped);
}
```

It would print `1` and `10` respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good solution IMO. That would require me coupling dependency down the entire stack.